# groovy.sql.Sql and Oracle errors

Tags: oracle, groovy

after updating Groovy to 2.4.12 from 2.4.6 we have resource problems:

**java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01000: maximum open cursors exceeded**

```
at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor87.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:437)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:83)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:105)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:247)
```

We tried to call "close" method after each sql operation but it did not resolve problem.

In version **2.4.9** we cannot even connect to database:

> 2017:11:07 10:31:17.465 [main] WARN  groovy.sql.Sql - Failed to execute: DELETE from USER_CONTEXT uc where uc.DOCUMENT.userId = ? because: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

While changing version of groovy we did not change database schema, SQL, nor updated drivers in use.

Now we are reverting to 2.4.6 and this is now big concern regarding usage of groovy Sql object.

Database is Oracle 12.1.
We are using JNDI connection pool defined on Liberty server.

Usage od SQL:

```
@Repository
class AuditLogRepository {

  Sql sql

  @Autowired
  AuditLogRepository(DataSource dataSource) {
    sql = new Sql(dataSource)
  }

  Long save(AuditLog auditLog) {
    def keys = sql.executeInsert(
        INSERT,
        [auditLog.callId, auditLog.userId, auditLog.auditPayloadJson],
        ["ID"])
    sql.close()
    keys[0][0] as Long
  }

  int[] bulkSave(List<AuditLog> auditLogs) {
    def saved = sql.withBatch INSERT, {
      ps ->
        auditLogs.forEach { auditLog ->
          ps.addBatch([auditLog.callId, auditLog.userId, auditLog.auditPayloadJson])
        }
    }
    sql.close()
    saved
  }

from Config class:
  @Bean(name = 'sql-bean')
  public Sql sqlBean(@Qualifier(value = 'datasource-hazelcast') DataSource dataSource){
    new Sql(dataSource)
  }

class OracleSessionMapStore implements MapStore<String, Session> {

 Sql sql

 OracleSessionMapStore() {
    sql = getApplicationContext().getBean('sql-bean')
    objectMapper = getApplicationContext().getBean(ObjectMapper.class)
  }

  void deleteExec(String userId, boolean batchDelete) {
    def params = [userId]
    sql.executeUpdate DELETE_QUERY, params
    if(!batchDelete)
       sql.close()
  }
```

My greatest concern/question when we updated Groovy version application was broken without changing anything else. Same database, same server, same connection pool, same code.

Please advice.

Comment: show some code, otherwise you'll be ignored

Comment: Try creating a JNDI connection pool in your app container. Unused connections can then be recycled.

Comment: The error message you have shown has nothing to do with too many open connections. It is telling you the table does not exist. It seems like your connection settings are not correct

Comment: How do you get _'we cannot even connect to database'_ from _ORA-00942: table or view does not exist_? That's an error from the database, so you must be connected.

Comment: How are you using the Sql object?  Connecting every time?  Using a datasource/pool?  I guess the answers are Yes and No if you're running out of connections

Comment: I have updated question based on comments.   The question is why we have such a strange behaviour and only think we changed is Groovy version. This code is working in production for more then a year.

Comment: can't connect database with error `table or view does not exist` - ihmo it's problem in your code or connection params. `maximum open cursors exceeded` - did you checked on the level of database what queries used to open cursors and not closed? why there is no commits in your code?

Comment: @daggett Application is Spring Boot and above repository layer there is transactional layer. On the same database after I reverted to version 2.4.6 everything continue to work normally.. We moved to Spring jdbcTemplate so we can upgrade Groovy and from now up we discourage usage of Groovy SQL...

Comment: @Samara, is it possible to create a executable pure groovy script/class that repeats the problem?